# Private Working Set Memory of a process is going up

Tags: memory

Private Working Set Memory of a process is going up.
Can I assume the process has a memory leak? 
If I add the Available and Free memory from task manager is about
constant when Private Working Set goes up.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assume the process has a memory leak. It's quite possible it is running a function that requires more and more memory and will subsequently release it. For example, perhaps it is processing a CSV file and caching the rows it has processed. Once it is finished with the CSV, it will clear the cache and release the memory.

It is obviously quite possible that it does indeed have a memory leak, but you can't make this conclusion based on the information you have provided.